# Dynamic Content block not showing background color in Outlook 2013 pc

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, email, ampscript

I am using Reference Dynamic Content in Content Builder. My layout has image on left and text on the right 2. Columns but in Outlook 2013 pc the background color is not showing up but if I don’t use dynamic content it works! Any help on that matter? Note: I need to use Dynamic Content because base on specific customer attribute show other content.

Comment: The problem might not be with the dynamic content but with the content Block itself. Outlook is extremely problematic

Comment: @Data_Kid : Is there any work around for this issue?

Comment: Are you using CSS or inline style tag?

Comment: if you could provide the html of the block that would be helpful as I believe @Data_Kid is correct. It is the styling used that is likely causing the issue. Outlook is the 'red headed stepchild' of email marketing.

Comment: @Gortonington : came up with a solution that I saved 2 images instead of using HTML for the right column. Note: I used 2 columns LAYOUT. Supposed to be image on left and text and CTA on right with a yellow background.